# Android (Oreo+) - setJustificationMode with ClickableSpan

Tags: android

I'd like to display a text inside a TextView justified with some of its content being clickable (e.g. a link inside).
The text is comming from xml, like the following example:

```
<string name="demo_text">Lorem <a href='http://www.google.at'>ipsum dolor sit amet</a>, consetetur sadipscing elitr ...</string>
```

For Android versions below Oreo, there is no justification available per default, whereas I'm using some 'legacy-implementation' of justification by directly drawing the text on the canvas.
=> This is working fine + hereby ClickableSpan touches are mapped within the View's onTouch().

Below you can find the used code.
Please note, that for Android Oreo and above, the default Android implementation of justification would be used.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.text.style.BackgroundColorSpan;
import android.text.style.CharacterStyle;
import android.text.style.ClickableSpan;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.text.style.StrikethroughSpan;
import android.text.style.StyleSpan;
import android.text.style.UnderlineSpan;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/* Base implementation found on: https://www.codementor.io/rugvedambekar/one-textview-to-rule-them-all-justifying-text-on-android-eq6ihy455
 *
 * Adapted to also support the following text spans:
 *      - BackgroundColorSpan
 *      - ForegroundColorSpan
 *      - StrikethroughSpan
 *      - UnderlineSpan
 *      - StyleSpan (bold / italic)
 *      - ClickableSpans
 *
 * TODO: possibile adaptions (bugfixes & improvements):
 *      - B: StrikethroughSpan & UnderlineSpan only apply to single words in justified lines
 *      - B: change getTextBounds() calculation for initial line-definitions to also include styles already
 *      - B: add the SpannableCharacterStyleMap to overridden setText()-methods as well (they'd change with API level 28)
 *      - I: get rid of Strings an use char-arrays instead
 */
public class JustifyTextView extends AppCompatTextView implements View.OnTouchListener {

    //ParagraphStyle spannables are not yet required though
    private class SpannableCharacterStyleMapping extends ArrayList<CharacterStyle> {

        private int mStartIndex;
        private int mEndIndex;

        SpannableCharacterStyleMapping(int startIndex, int endIndex, CharacterStyle[] characterStyles) {
            super();
            mStartIndex = startIndex;
            mEndIndex = endIndex;

            if (characterStyles != null) {
                addAll(Arrays.asList(characterStyles));
            }
        }

        ClickableSpan getClickableSpan() {
            for(CharacterStyle characterStyle : this) {
                if (characterStyle instanceof ClickableSpan) {
                    return (ClickableSpan)characterStyle;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private class SpannableCharacterStyleMap extends ArrayList<SpannableCharacterStyleMapping> {
        SpannableCharacterStyleMap() {
            super();
        }

        SpannableCharacterStyleMap(Spanned styledText) {
            super();
            createFromText(styledText);
        }

        void createFromText(Spanned styledText) {
            clear();

            //avoid iterating over empty string
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(styledText)) return;

            int next;
            for (int i = 0; i < styledText.length(); i = next) {
                //find the next span transition (if none was found, styledText.length() will be returned resulting in the loop to end)
                next = styledText.nextSpanTransition(i, styledText.length(), CharacterStyle.class);

                if ((next - 1) >= i) {
                    //check for all character style spans within this range
                    CharacterStyle[] spansInRange = styledText.getSpans(i, next, CharacterStyle.class);
                    if (spansInRange.length > 0) {
                        //spans in range have been found ... thus add them to our mapping!
                        add(new SpannableCharacterStyleMapping(i, next, spansInRange));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ArrayList<SpannableCharacterStyleMapping> getStylesWithinRange(int start, int end) {
            ArrayList<SpannableCharacterStyleMapping> stylesInRange = new ArrayList<>();

            for (SpannableCharacterStyleMapping styleMapping : this) {
                if ((start <= styleMapping.mStartIndex && end > styleMapping.mStartIndex) ||
                    (start < styleMapping.mEndIndex && end >= styleMapping.mEndIndex) ||
                    (start >= styleMapping.mStartIndex && end <= styleMapping.mEndIndex)) {
                    stylesInRange.add(styleMapping);
                }
            }

            return stylesInRange;
        }

        boolean hasClickableStylesWithinRange(int start, int end) {
            for (SpannableCharacterStyleMapping styleMapping : this) {
                if (((start <= styleMapping.mStartIndex && end > styleMapping.mStartIndex) ||
                    (start < styleMapping.mEndIndex && end >= styleMapping.mEndIndex) ||
                    (start >= styleMapping.mStartIndex && end <= styleMapping.mEndIndex)) &&
                    styleMapping.getClickableSpan() != null) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    private int mFirstLineTextHeight = 0;
    private Rect mLineBounds = new Rect();

    private SpannableCharacterStyleMap mCharacterStylesMap;

    private int mDefaultTextBg;
    private int mDefaultTextFg;
    private int mDefaultTextHighlightFg;
    private Typeface mDefaultTypeface;
    private boolean mDefaultTextStrikethrough;
    private boolean mDefaultTextUnderline;

    private HashMap<ClickableSpan, ArrayList<RectF>> mClickableSpanAreas;

    public JustifyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public JustifyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public JustifyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mClickableSpanAreas = new HashMap<>();

        CharSequence textViewText = getText();
        mCharacterStylesMap = new SpannableCharacterStyleMap(new SpannableString(textViewText));

        //check if we can actually use the default implementation (Android Oreo and above)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            super.setJustificationMode(Layout.JUSTIFICATION_MODE_INTER_WORD);

            //check if there are clickable spans (if so, they should be clickable)
            if (mCharacterStylesMap.hasClickableStylesWithinRange(0, textViewText.length())) {
                setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            }
            return;
        }

        //check if there are clickable spans
        if (mCharacterStylesMap.hasClickableStylesWithinRange(0, textViewText.length())) {
            setClickable(true);
            setFocusable(true);
            setOnTouchListener(this);
        }

        //now remember the default styles
        mDefaultTextBg = getPaint().bgColor;
        mDefaultTextFg = getCurrentTextColor();
        mDefaultTextHighlightFg = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN ? getHighlightColor() : mDefaultTextFg;
        mDefaultTypeface = getPaint().getTypeface();
        mDefaultTextStrikethrough = getPaint().isStrikeThruText();
        mDefaultTextUnderline = getPaint().isUnderlineText();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //check if we can actually use the default implementation (Android Oreo and above)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            return;
        }

        if (mClickableSpanAreas != null) {
            mClickableSpanAreas.clear();
        }

        //so we cannot use the default-Android implementation ... stick to the 'compatibility' code of ours
        TextPaint paint = getPaint();
        paint.drawableState = getDrawableState();

        resetStyling(paint); //apply default styling at first

        String fullText = getText().toString();

        float drawableWidth = getDrawableWidth();

        int lineNum = 1, lineStartIndex = 0;
        int lastWordEnd, currWordEnd = 0;

        while (currWordEnd >= 0) {
            lastWordEnd = currWordEnd + 1;
            currWordEnd = fullText.indexOf(' ', lastWordEnd);

            if (currWordEnd != -1) {
                paint.getTextBounds(fullText, lineStartIndex, currWordEnd, mLineBounds);

                if (mLineBounds.width() >= drawableWidth) {
                    flushLine(canvas, paint, lineNum, lineStartIndex, fullText.substring(lineStartIndex, lastWordEnd));
                    lineStartIndex = lastWordEnd;
                    lineNum++;
                }

            } else {
                paint.getTextBounds(fullText, lineStartIndex, fullText.length(), mLineBounds);

                if (mLineBounds.width() >= drawableWidth) {
                    flushLine(canvas, paint, lineNum, lineStartIndex, fullText.substring(lineStartIndex, lastWordEnd));
                    rawFlushLine(canvas, paint, ++lineNum, lastWordEnd, fullText.substring(lastWordEnd));
                } else {
                    if (lineNum == 1) {
                        rawFlushLine(canvas, paint, lineNum, lineStartIndex, fullText);
                    }
                    else {
                        rawFlushLine(canvas, paint, lineNum, lineStartIndex, fullText.substring(lineStartIndex));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void resetStyling(TextPaint paint) {
        //revert to defaults (luckily remembered previously) here
        paint.bgColor = mDefaultTextBg;                     //BackgroundColorSpan
        paint.setColor(mDefaultTextFg);                     //ForegroundColorSpan
        paint.setTypeface(mDefaultTypeface);                //StyleSpan
        paint.setStrikeThruText(mDefaultTextStrikethrough); //StrikethroughSpan
        paint.setUnderlineText(mDefaultTextUnderline);      //UnderlineSpan
    }

    private void applyStyling(TextPaint paint, SpannableCharacterStyleMapping styling) {
        resetStyling(paint);

        if (styling != null && styling.size() > 0) {
            //sadly a StyleSpan won't combine bold & italic already on its own ...
            boolean fontShallBeBold = false;
            boolean fontShallBeItalic = false;

            //apply defined styling here now
            for (CharacterStyle style : styling) {
                if (style instanceof BackgroundColorSpan) {
                    paint.bgColor = ((BackgroundColorSpan) style).getBackgroundColor();
                } else if (style instanceof ForegroundColorSpan) {
                    paint.setColor(((ForegroundColorSpan) style).getForegroundColor());
                } else if (style instanceof StrikethroughSpan) {
                    paint.setStrikeThruText(true);
                } else if (style instanceof UnderlineSpan) {
                    paint.setUnderlineText(true);
                } else if (style instanceof ClickableSpan) {
                    paint.setColor(mDefaultTextHighlightFg);
                    // right now, the text will be rendered word by word, whereas underlining works only word by word right now
                    // => thus skip underlining in this scenario, until it is 'fixed' (only will be fixed if indeed necessary)
                    paint.setUnderlineText(false);
                } else if (style instanceof StyleSpan) {
                    switch (((StyleSpan) style).getStyle()) {
                        case Typeface.BOLD:
                            fontShallBeBold = true;
                            break;
                        case Typeface.ITALIC:
                            fontShallBeItalic = true;
                            break;
                        case Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC:
                            fontShallBeBold = true;
                            fontShallBeItalic = true;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            //in the end apply the StyleSpan bold & italic params (if set)
            if (fontShallBeBold && fontShallBeItalic) {
                paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC));
            } else if (fontShallBeBold) {
                paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD));
            } else if (fontShallBeItalic) {
                paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.ITALIC));
            }
        }
    }

    private float getDrawableWidth() {
        return getMeasuredWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
    }

    private void setFirstLineTextHeight(TextPaint paint, String firstLine) {
        paint.getTextBounds(firstLine, 0, firstLine.length(), mLineBounds);
        mFirstLineTextHeight = mLineBounds.height();
    }

    //Prints the line at lineNum on the canvas without adjusting the spacing between words at all.
    private void rawFlushLine(Canvas canvas, TextPaint paint, int lineNum, int lineCharacterStart, String line) {
        if (lineNum == 1) setFirstLineTextHeight(paint, line);

        float yLine = getPaddingTop() + mFirstLineTextHeight + (lineNum - 1) * getLineHeight();
        flushStyledText(canvas, paint, getPaddingLeft(), yLine, lineCharacterStart, line);
    }

    //Calculates the space between all words required to strech the line out to fit the full width of the view.
    private void flushLine(Canvas canvas, TextPaint paint, int lineNum, int lineCharacterStart, String line) {
        if (lineNum == 1) setFirstLineTextHeight(paint, line);

        float yLine = getPaddingTop() + mFirstLineTextHeight + (lineNum - 1) * getLineHeight();

        String[] words = line.split("\\s+");
        StringBuilder lineBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (String word : words) {
            lineBuilder.append(word);
        }

        float xStart = getPaddingLeft();
        float wordWidth = paint.measureText(lineBuilder.toString());
        float spacingWidth = (getDrawableWidth() - wordWidth) / (words.length - 1);

        for (String word : words) {
            flushStyledText(canvas, paint, xStart, yLine, lineCharacterStart, word);
            resetStyling(paint); //before checking new text bounds, revert paint
            xStart += paint.measureText(word) + spacingWidth;
            lineCharacterStart += word.length() + 1;
        }
    }

    private void flushStyledText(Canvas canvas, TextPaint paint, float posX, float posY, int textPositionStart, String text) {
        int textPositionEnd = textPositionStart + text.length();
        ArrayList<SpannableCharacterStyleMapping> stylesInText = mCharacterStylesMap.getStylesWithinRange(textPositionStart, textPositionEnd);

        if (stylesInText.size() > 0) {
            int styleIndex = 0;
            int textPositionNext;
            ClickableSpan clickableSpan;
            for (int textPosition = textPositionStart; textPosition < textPositionEnd; textPosition = textPositionNext) {
                if (styleIndex <= stylesInText.size() - 1) {
                    SpannableCharacterStyleMapping styleToPossiblyApply = stylesInText.get(styleIndex);
                    if (styleToPossiblyApply.mStartIndex <= textPosition) {
                        //this style shall be applied now
                        applyStyling(paint, styleToPossiblyApply);
                        clickableSpan = styleToPossiblyApply.getClickableSpan();
                        textPositionNext = Math.min(textPositionEnd, styleToPossiblyApply.mEndIndex);
                        styleIndex++;
                    } else {
                        //this style shall not yet be applied => coming up next
                        resetStyling(paint);
                        clickableSpan = null;
                        textPositionNext = Math.min(textPositionEnd, styleToPossiblyApply.mStartIndex);
                    }
                } else {
                    resetStyling(paint);
                    clickableSpan = null;
                    textPositionNext = textPositionEnd;
                }

                String textToDraw = text.substring(textPosition - textPositionStart, textPositionNext - textPositionStart);
                canvas.drawText(textToDraw, posX, posY, paint);

                if (clickableSpan != null && mClickableSpanAreas != null) {
                    ArrayList<RectF> clickableSpanAreaList = null;
                    if (mClickableSpanAreas.containsKey(clickableSpan)) {
                        clickableSpanAreaList = mClickableSpanAreas.get(clickableSpan);
                    } else {
                        clickableSpanAreaList = new ArrayList<>();
                        mClickableSpanAreas.put(clickableSpan, clickableSpanAreaList);
                    }
                    clickableSpanAreaList.add(new RectF(posX, posY, posX + paint.measureText(textToDraw), posY + getLineHeight()));
                }
            }
        } else {
            resetStyling(paint);
            canvas.drawText(text, posX, posY, paint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        //check if the touch ended inside a clickable span area => if so, execute its click listener
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && mClickableSpanAreas != null) {
            for (Map.Entry<ClickableSpan, ArrayList<RectF>> clickableAreaList : mClickableSpanAreas.entrySet()) {
                if (clickableAreaList.getValue() != null) {
                    for (RectF clickableArea : clickableAreaList.getValue()) {
                        if (clickableArea.contains(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                            clickableAreaList.getKey().onClick(this);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, if I'd like to use the default implementation of [setJustificationMode(Layout.JUSTIFICATION_MODE_INTER_WORD)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setJustificationMode(int)) on Android Oreo or above, I'm facing the following scenarios:

1. ClickableSpans are not clickable (but still highlightened) but text is justified
2. ClickableSpans are clickable due to calling [setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setMovementMethod(android.text.method.MovementMethod)) but the text no longer is justified

Therefore I'm wondering if someone knows any way of making ClickableSpan clickable with keeping the justification mode on Android Oreo and above.
(Or maybe if there is any way of making URLSpan clickable without applying the LinkMovementMethod.)

Thanks. BR Thomas

Comment: Ever find a solution for this? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: I was facing the same problem and found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68660290/justificationmode-with-linkmovementmethod-make-text-cut-off