# justificationMode with LinkMovementMethod make text cut off

Tags: android, textview

I want to achieve both justify text and add a link (show more) to `TextView` so I use `justificationMode` with `movementMethod`.
`justificationMode` working well but after set `movementMethod`, some last character on each line of my TextView is cut.

```
val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.myTextView)
textView.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuabc adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
textView.justificationMode = JUSTIFICATION_MODE_INTER_WORD
textView.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod()
```

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

8 months later, this issue is still here and I just ran into it on SDK 31. The `android:autoLink="all"` workaround did not work for me and was also unsatisfactory for my application. Here is my workaround; it's not perfect but it solved the issue for me, and I think there is enough here to fix OP's issue while providing guidance for others:

**1. Add OnTouchListener to TextView**

```
// A lot of this code was lifted from LinkMovementMethod.onTouchEvent
binding.tv.setOnTouchListener { tv, event ->
        require(tv is TextView)
        val action = event.action
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            val x = event.x.toInt() - tv.totalPaddingLeft + tv.scrollX
            val y = event.y.toInt() - tv.totalPaddingTop + tv.scrollY
            val line = tv.layout.getLineForVertical(y)
            val offset = tv.layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x.toFloat())
            val spannable = tv.text as SpannedString // Risky business
            val links: Array<ClickableSpan> = spannable.getSpans(offset, offset, ClickableSpan::class.java)
            if (links.isNotEmpty()) {
                logger.debug("x=${event.x}; y=${event.y}")
                links.first().onClick(tv)
            }
        }
        true
    }
```

**2. Add ClickableSpans to TextView**

```
val builder = SpannableStringBuilder()
builder.setSpan(object : ClickableSpan() {
    // You can cache data here using closure
    val textOrUrl = "Clicked!"
    override fun onClick(widget: View) {
        // Do stuff
        Toast.makeText(widget.context, textOrUrl, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    // optional override if you don't want your links formatted
    override fun updateDrawState(ds: TextPaint) = Unit
}, beginIndex, endIndex, 0)
// Add builder to TextView 
binding.tv.text = builder
```

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as @not43s but written in Java:

```
    binding.termsTextView.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
        if(v instanceof TextView){
            TextView tv = (TextView) v;
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                int x = (int) (event.getX() - tv.getTotalPaddingLeft() + tv.getScrollX());
                int y = (int) (event.getY() - tv.getTotalPaddingTop() + tv.getScrollY());
                int line = tv.getLayout().getLineForVertical(y);
                int offset = tv.getLayout().getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);
                if(tv.getText()instanceof Spanned) {
                    Spanned spannable = (Spanned) tv.getText();
                    ClickableSpan[] links =spannable.getSpans(offset, offset, ClickableSpan.class);
                    if (links.length>0) {
                        links[0].onClick(tv);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    });


    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(gdrpMessage);
    setClickableSpan(builder,termsOfService,termsLink);
    setClickableSpan(builder,privacyPolicy,privacyLink);
    // Add builder to TextView
    binding.termsTextView.setText(builder);
```

and setClickableSpan() used above:

```
void setClickableSpan(SpannableStringBuilder builder, String clickableString, String link){
    String originalString = builder.toString();
    int startIdx = originalString.indexOf(clickableString);
    int endIdx = startIdx + clickableString.length();
    builder.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(@NonNull View widget) {
            Toast.makeText(PremiumActivity.this, link, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    },startIdx,endIdx,0);
}
```

Comment: This works great! Instead of setMovementMethod I added this listener to my text view and it worked. My textView text came from Html.fromHtml(releaseNotes, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY) so no need to manually create the spans. The only thing I added was right after links[0].onClick(tv); I added the click sound effect tv.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the solution I found was to use the `android:autoLink="all"` tag on my Textview, instead of using LinkMovementMethod...

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, it works without any issues:

```
public class CustomLinkMovementMethod extends LinkMovementMethod {
private static CustomLinkMovementMethod instance;
public static MovementMethod getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new CustomLinkMovementMethod();
    }
    return instance;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(TextView widget, Spannable buffer, MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();

    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();
        x -= widget.getTotalPaddingLeft();
        y -= widget.getTotalPaddingTop();
        x += widget.getScrollX();
        y += widget.getScrollY();
        Layout layout = widget.getLayout();
        int line = layout.getLineForVertical(y);
        int off = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);
        ClickableSpan[] link = buffer.getSpans(off, off, ClickableSpan.class);
        if (link.length != 0) {
            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                link[0].onClick(widget);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return Touch.onTouchEvent(widget, buffer, event);
}
```

}

The variables x and y contain adjusted coordinates of the press, which are used to determine the position in the text (Layout) and to check for the presence of a hyperlink at that position.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your answer, why does this work and what changes did you make?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).